# String concatenation in Perl

Tags: perl, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate this string in Perl: "/.hush_profile";

I keep getting a problem when I add in "/" into the string. I've tried escaping it, but that won't work either.

Here's my line of problem code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my($fileloc, $home_dir);

$home_dir = $ENV{"HOME"};
$fileloc = $home_dir;
$fileloc .= "/.hush_profile";
```

Comment: It refuses to concatenate. The variable comes out empty.

Comment: And $fileloc has a value to begin with so I'm not trying to concatenate to null.

Comment: So you're saying that the following does nothing:  `my $fileloc = "something"; $fileloc .= "/.hush_profile"; print $fileloc, "\n";`?  If *that* works, then you need to show more code.

Comment: That does not work. Should I show more code? And that is basically what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes; you need to show the minimal code that reproduces the problem.  Are you using `use strict; use warnings;`?

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://ideone.com/tSNmtj)

Comment: Have you printed out `$home_dir`?  Have you run that code?  It gives compilation errors because you've not use `my $home_dir;`.

Comment: I forgot to add $home_dir in my declaration. I've printed out $home_dir and $fileloc before concatenation and it all works fine. I then print out $fileloc after concatenation and it will print out empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This adaptation of your code gives me the expected output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my($fileloc);

my $home_dir = $ENV{"HOME"};
print "home_dir = $home_dir\n";
$fileloc = $home_dir;
print "fileloc 1 = $fileloc\n";
$fileloc .= "/.hush_profile";
print "fileloc 2 = $fileloc\n";
```

Output:

```
home_dir = /work4/jleffler
fileloc 1 = /work4/jleffler
fileloc 2 = /work4/jleffler/.hush_profile
```

Even if I unset `$HOME` in the environment, I get something:

```
$ (unset HOME; perl x.pl)
Use of uninitialized value $home_dir in concatenation (.) or string at x.pl line 6.
home_dir = 
Use of uninitialized value $fileloc in concatenation (.) or string at x.pl line 8.
fileloc 1 = 
fileloc 2 = /.hush_profile
$
```

This happens to be Perl 5.12.1 on RHEL 5 (x86/64), but I get the same with Perl 5.8.8 on the same platform.

Comment: I'm glad this helped, but it was mainly too hard to fit in a comment (especially given the lack of formatting in comments).  Since you accepted this, it must have pointed you to a solution — can you share what that was?  (In case of doubt, wall-to-wall printing of variables often helps, I find.)

Comment: The solution was as simple as it looks. I had a small syntax error that I caught when I was looking at your code and comparing it to mine.

Comment: It happens; bad luck.  I'm glad this helped.